# Mongo::Error::OperationFailure (not authorized on [my_db] to execute command)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I'm using Rails 5.2.0, Ruby 2.5.0 and MongoId 7.1.0,

Everything was worked OK, but I using this code bellow to get information about size of collections. But now it fail with error:

```
Mongo::Error::OperationFailure (not authorized on[mydb] to execute command { $eval: "
    var collectionNames = db.getCollectionNames(), stats = [];
    collectionNames.forEach(function (n) { stats.push(db[n].stats()); });
    stats = ...", args: [], nolock: true, $db: "super_control_development", $readPreference: { mode: "primary" } } (13)):
```

The code is:

```
db ||= Mongoid.default_client.database

# db = Mongoid::Config.clients[:default][:database]
f = """
var collectionNames = db.getCollectionNames(), stats = [];
collectionNames.forEach(function (n) { stats.push(db[n].stats()); });
stats = stats.sort(function(a, b) { return b['size'] - a['size']; });
return stats;
"""
result = db.command({:$eval => f, args: [], nolock: true})
@result_data = result.first['retval']
```

ANY BODY HELP ME?

More information:

- options in my mongoid.yml is

{"database"=>"mydb", "user"=>"owner", "password"=>"mypass", "auth_source"=>"super_control_development", "platform"=>"mongoid-7.1.0"}

- In mongo shell in terminal, code worked well without errors.

THANK YOU.

Comment: Means exactly what it says. The current user is **not authorized** to use the `eval` command on the server. You really should not be using `eval` anyway since it is deprecated and marked for removal. That means your code **will cease to work** in future releases. Anything you are attempting to run in JavaScript code can be run using the language native driver anyway. That is what you are supposed to be doing.

Comment: @NeilLunn, thank you for your comment. But i was `db.grantRolesToUser("owner",["readWrite"])`, and test it in mongo shell, but I want to it in controller of Rails, how i can run all command if i don't use $eval?

Comment: `eval` requires a special privelage. The `"readWrite"` role is not enough to be able to execute this, since you can do "nasty" things with it. You're not listening though **YOU DO NOT WANT EVAL**. Write the code with the "ruby driver" instead. All methods are available in the standard API.

Comment: If you don't mind, please give me some information about size in stats of collections in API standard in ruby drive. Thanks.

Comment: The documentation is freely available. For instance [`Database::collections`](http://api.mongodb.com/ruby/current/Mongo/Database.html#collections-instance_method). Everything you can do in the shell you can do in the driver. If there's not a direct method, then use `command` and any [command operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/), You don't need to execute JavaScript for any of this.